# Communicate safely between head script and body script (if possible)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bundle script that loads my app in the body.
I wrote a script in the head of my site in order to harden some JS functionalities related to my web app.
I load 3rd party scripts between those scripts (between the hardening script in head and the app script in body).

I need to get some data in the head and to be able to give it to the app script in the body.
Is there any safe (client side) way to communicate between each other? I don't want that 3rd party scripts to be able to get that data.

I don't want to add server side communications since it will cost me in performance until site is loaded.
I cannot move any code from the places it suppose to be.

Thanks in advance.

I've tried custom messaging with crypto but this can still be copied from 3rd party script in the middle.

Comment: Why you are using 3rd party scripts that you don't trust?

Comment: assign any object to `window` and communicate with it. it could be either object, class instance or event bus

Comment: @JaromandaX - it's a feature of the site to be able to load 3rd party scripts in the head.

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev - this way the 3rd party scripts will be able to get that info as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tenuous situation to be in and really should be avoided if you can. You should firstly realise that essentially anything in the client (browser) is insecure and unsafe and available to a wide range of malicious access. From rogue browser plugins to network sniffing, you need to accept that client-side code is accessible.

There is no practical way to stop the third party scripts from reading your source code (in either script). Even adding some kind of server/client interaction would be able to be decoded by the scripts.

It may be an unreasonable request to solve this problem, the client is inherently insecure and cannot the trusted. It's all about managing these expectations and realities of working with a browser solution.

There are maybe some ways to bolster the security of the client-side code. See below.

### Some ideas

#### 1. Sandbox the third party scripts

You could work with the project to somehow isolate what the third party scripts can do. Maybe look at https://partytown.builder.io/

#### 2. CSP and `nonce` for third party scripts

You could explore a CSP restriction approach, this allows you to stop any third party scripts from pulling in other unknown scripts.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Combined with `noonce` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/nonce - you can be quite confident (but not 100%) that you know the content of the third party scripts won't change.

#### 3. Server side cross communication

While you said you want to avoid a server side solution, the only secure place is your server. You could set up a small RPC style call and a server session for the two scripts to communicate.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I will look into those and update here.